# Request to http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp failed, response=Forbidden

Tags: aem

I have faced this issue while building project when my office network restricted to access the Adobe CRX packmgr while build through Vault.

```
The error message were as below:

[WARNING] Required proxy credentials not available for BASIC <any realm>@10.XX3.X0.XX:XXXX
[WARNING] Preemptive authentication requested but no default proxy credentials available
[ERROR] Request to http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp failed, response=Forbidden

And the Build was failed.


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.221 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-22T16:01:01+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/459M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.24:install (install-package) on project XXXbas.ui.apps: Error while installing package. Check log for details. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved this issue by adding a simple configuration in my parent pom.xml:

`<useProxy>false</useProxy>`

Below is the code:

```
<!-- Content Package Plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.24</version>
    <configuration>
        <targetURL>http://${aem.host}:${aem.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
        <useProxy>false</useProxy>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Would you please accept this answer just for clarity that this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Me, I have created a second instance of aem, where i changed my password from admin to something else. So, I would be required to change my password in my root project's pom.xml file as well.

```js
<properties>
        <aem.host>localhost</aem.host>
        <aem.port>4502</aem.port>
        <aem.publish.host>localhost</aem.publish.host>
        <aem.publish.port>4503</aem.publish.port>
        <sling.user>admin</sling.user>
        <sling.password>admin</sling.password>
        <vault.user>*add_your_password*</vault.user>
        <vault.password>**ADD_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE**</vault.password>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
```

As you can observe, that ADD_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE is where you should change the password with your given instance password.

This worked for me. Hope it works for you too...